# How to use Laravel Eloquent to pass a single row of data to View?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I am very new to Laravel. I am still learning the concepts. I tried to google this problem but i don't think I know what to type?

I am retrieving a single row, single column of data from my database using this code in my controller.

```
$companyName = Homepage::select('contents')->where('section', 'Company Name') ->get();
echo $companyName;
```

The echo showed in my view is:

```
[{"contents":"Example Company Ltd"}]
```

I know this is pretty basic but what can I do to make sure it only echo "Example Company Ltd"?

Thank you for any help answering this. I am really new.

I tried something like

```
echo $companyName->get('contents');
```

Comment: `first()` instead of `get()`, usually.

Comment: Be aware that `->first()` can also return `null` if there's no record that matches the criteria defined in your `where()` clause, and `null->contents` is not valid code. Neither of the answers below handle that... You can use `->firstOrFail()` to trigger a `ModelNotFoundException` (which typically triggers an `HTTP 404` error), or you can check the variable before accessing, like `if ($companyName) { return $companyName->contents; }`, or "safe access", which is `return `$companyName?->contents;`, which will return the `contents` value, or `null` if `$companyName` is `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you are trying to get the first item. You can try

```
$companyName = Homepage::select('contents')->where('section', 'Company Name')->first();
echo $companyName->contents;
```

As to why `first()` instead of `get()`, then `get()`returns a collection where as `first()` returns a single model instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
$companyContents = Homepage::where('section', 'Company Name')
               ->first()
               ->pluck('contents');

echo $companyContents;
```

You can use pluck instead of select, this will return only the relevant columns of a Model